# Rails `select where` returns id nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I write in console:

```
Avatar.where(username: 'alizade').select('avatar').last
```

And it prints the next:

```
  Avatar Load (4.6ms)  SELECT  "avatars"."avatar" FROM "avatars"  WHERE "avatars"."username" = 'alizade'  ORDER BY "avatars"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  => #<Avatar id: nil, avatar: "bookdribbble.png">
```

So, why it returns

```
#<Avatar id: nil,
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're only selecting the `avatar` field, and not the `id` field. Hence, no value.

Comment: No. When I select both of them(id, avatar) it returns `#<Avatar id: 24, avatar: "bookdribbble.png">`.

Comment: Exactly. The example you posted in the question didn't select the `id` field, so you didn't get the ID. When you do select the `id`, you get the ID as well.

Comment: No, I did not mean it. Always I get just the result, without the `#<Avatar id` part. So, how can I get just `avatar: "bookdribbble.png"` this part?

Comment: If you want an array of just the avatar values, you might try using `pluck`, instead of `select`.

Comment: Why does the default behavior return the 'id' attribute with nil values? Is this helpful in some way? Since the 'id' field is returned by default even when it's not specifically listed in the arguments, wouldn't it be preferable to give the actual 'id' value?

Comment: The `id` field isn't returned by default. The SQL query in the question will return just a set of avatar strings - no IDs in sight. If you want the IDs, you must select them.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something. If I have a User class and I call `users = User.select("email")`, the return is `#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: nil, email: "travis@example.com">]>`. I can then call `users.first.id`, and the value of `nil` is returned. But, if I call `users.first.name`, I get a `MissingAttributeError`. So, it seems the default is to return the `id` attribute with a `nil` value. I'm wondering what the benefit of that is? If the attribute is returned, why not populate it with the actual `id`?

Comment: I think you'll find that the actual IDs aren't getting returned by the SQL, but ActiveRecord is making some assumptions that all records will have primary key fields defined. It's like when you instantiate a new record - it has an `id` field with value nil, even though it has no data from the database.